# Freebase; select a random record?

Tags: freebase, mql

1) Is there any way to select a random record from Freebase?  If I do a limit of 1, it consistently returns the same record. I could grab the larger data set and select a random rec from that but that seems like overkill.  Analogous to MySQL's :

```
select * from profiles order by rand() limit 1;
```

2)  Is there any way to tell Freebase not to select certain items in a set?

Analogous to MySQL's :

```
select * from profiles  where id NOT IN (SELECT profile_id from approved_profiles)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, right now MQL doesn't have a random operator. This [thread](http://freebase.markmail.org/thread/vcjpe5sm537ouehs) on the Freebase discussion list suggests using a random [as_of_time](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch04.html#envelopeparameters) parameter as a work-around.

Comment: No random yet? I'm trying to get a random element by using the count (~30.000 records) and using "page" in the Envelope in a second query, but in the last 70% pages it takes forever.